# Stopped unexpectedly error when capturing a button from layout

Tags: java, android

I want to capture a ImageButton in java and define a onClick event listener for it.
But in capturing line application stopped unexpectaly.
Im using API Level 8.

this is my java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Login extends Activity {
    ImageButton buttonTest =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        buttonTest.setOnClickListener(strLogoAnim);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);

        return true;
    }

    private OnClickListener strLogoAnim = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // Do something
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }

}
```

even I create a new project and test it.but this problem exist too.
where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ImageButton buttonTest =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        buttonTest.setOnClickListener(strLogoAnim);
    }
```

Try this.

Comment: @SajjadRad then you have something funny in OnClickListener. Post your logcat output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the button in onCreate:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    ImageButton buttonTest; // remove this: =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        buttonTest =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); // add this
        buttonTest.setOnClickListener(strLogoAnim);
    }
```